# Vim editor showing some blue characters but cannot reach it

Tags: json, vim, dataset, buffer

I was editing some data and when I checked the json file it's showing some blue chars like "<202b>202>" and "b>". I can see them through the vim but I can not change them or even find them. [image: screenshot of vim]

When I print the texts in python, also python doesn't see them and just printing the normal texts. Are those chars important? How can I get rid of them? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<202b>` is how Vim represents the character [U+202B](https://unicode-table.com/en/202B/), the presence of which kind of makes sense because your data appears to be a mix of left-to-right and right-to-left scripts.

You can't search it with `/<202b>` because the characters `<202b>` are not actually in the text, it is just how Vim displays the character `U+202B` when it encounters it.

You can:

- insert that character with `<C-v>u202b`, see `:help i_ctrl-v_digit`,
- search for it with `/\%u202b`, see `:help /\%u`.

[image: example]

As for getting rid of them… it depends on whether they are here accidentally or purposely.